# Magento getSearchCriterias() method and its array composition

Tags: php, magento

I'm looking inside the class Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Result and, i don't why, during the $searchcriterias array composition, developers uses this kind of strange script:

```
public function getSearchCriterias()
{
    $searchCriterias = $this->getSearchModel()->getSearchCriterias();
    $middle = ceil(count($searchCriterias) / 2);
    $left = array_slice($searchCriterias, 0, $middle);
    $right = array_slice($searchCriterias, $middle);

    return array('left'=>$left, 'right'=>$right);
}
```

Why they divide the array into $left and $right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be usability reasons.

Splitting the search criterias like they do allows to easily display them as a 2-column block (the standard Magento template `catalogsearch/advanced/result.phtml` uses two `<ul>`'s for this).

A 2-column block of search criterias usually takes lesser height than a 1-column block would do, so the user will see **more results at once** below a 2-column block, than he could below a 1-column block.